# IF performance on DAX formula

Tags: performance, if-statement, dax, ssas-tabular

i am stuck on simple performance problem.
i have a RunningBalance formula. I have no problem with this formula. It gives me the last nonempty value of balance.  (i have the balance on rows.)

Then i try to write another formula with using this formula.
Aim is simple. New formula sould show me nothing(BLANK()) when it is <=0

i tried

```
RunningBalance:=CALCULATE (
    SUM ( DebitsAndCredits[balance]  );
    LASTNONBLANK (
        'Date'[Day];
        CALCULATE ( SUM (DebitsAndCredits[balance] ) )
    )
)
```

[image]

```
Newformula:=CALCULATE ( IF ( [RunningBalance] <= 0; BLANK (); [RunningBalance] ) )
```

i wrote this simple formula. But it is very slow when i use DocumentNumber on rows.

How can i make this formula faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Without variables

I would slightly change the requirement and try to change the IF as:

```
Newformula:=
MAX(0, [RunningBalance])
```

#### Using Variables

A possible enhancement is the following:

```
RunningBalance:=
VAR _V1 = SUM (DebitsAndCredits[balance] )
RETURN
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( DebitsAndCredits[balance]  );
    LASTNONBLANK (
        'Date'[Day];
        _V1)
    )
)
```

and,

```
Newformula:=
VAR _V1 =  [RunningBalance]
RETURN
CALCULATE ( IF ( _V1 <= 0; BLANK (); _V1 ) )
```

I would also check if the following expression gives you the correct result:

```
RunningBalance:=
VAR _V1 = SUM (DebitsAndCredits[balance] )
RETURN
CALCULATE (
    _V1;
    LASTNONBLANK (
        'Date'[Day];
        _V1)
    )
)
```

Otherwise, I would investigate the need of using LASTNONBLANK() and maybe find a different implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but i can not use VAR function because of my Analysis Server version. :(

Comment: It is SQL Server 2012 AS Tabular Edition. And i am using VStudio 2010 to design it. It gives Query (78, 57) Parser: The syntax for '_V1' is incorrect. Error when i try to add your formulas

Comment: Yikes. DAX without VAR is painful.

Comment: @CemÜney I update my answer. Please check MAX(0, [RunningBalance])

Comment: "Too many arguments were passed to the MAX function. The maximum argument count for the function is 1." ooops

Comment: Can't you update the compatibility version? I mean that is almost 10 years old..